# Is there a concise way to check if an int variable is equal to a series of ints? | C#

Tags: c#

Rather than something like this:

```
switch (id) {
case 2:
case 5:
case 11:
case 15:
...
}
```

Is there a concise way to check if an int variable is equal to any one of a series of integers? Maybe something like `if (id == {2|5|11|15}) ...`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could put all the ints into a HashSet and do a contains.

```
Hashset<int> ids = new HashSet<int>() {...initialize...};

if(ids.Contains(id)){
...
}
```

Comment: Thanks... never used a Hashset. After a bit of searching, turns out they're AWESOME (cause they're fast). http://www.vcskicks.com/hashset.php

Comment: In the case you are talking about with the checking for certain values you'd have to do some testing when compared to the switch statement as far as performance.  They should be relatively close but the HashSet is probably slightly slower.  Also be careful about the birthday problem.  Eric Lippert explains it nicely here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/03/22/socks-birthdays-and-hash-collisions.aspx

Comment: Thanks... in this case I just wanted to check if a given int was one that was contained in those few numbers. It won't scale any larger. Thanks for leading me to HashSets, much appreciated.

Comment: @Chad, @Craig: incidentally, the compiler will itself generate a hash table to codegen the switch if it believes that doing so will make the switch code faster and smaller.

Comment: Thanks Eric, that's a great insight into this; I really appreciate your addition to this topic.

Comment: @Eric Thanks for the detail on that.  I had a hunch that's how it would deal with multiple conditions in the switch, but didn't check the switch.  Is the hash table created by the compiler equivalent to the HashSet or does it more efficient because its a lower level construct?

Answer (score 4):

```
if((new List<int> { 2, 5, 11, 15}).Contains(id))
```

But you probably don't want to create a new `List` instance every time, so it would be better to create it in the constructor of your class.

Comment: Maybe if it were `if((new HashSet<int> {2,5,11,15}).Contains(id)){...}` it would be performant? http://www.vcskicks.com/hashset.php

Comment: With that few elements, there won't be any difference in performance. The problem is the creation of the object, not the search.

Comment: Good point... lol, would not be an issue with that few elements... guess I got my mind stuck in "pure performance" mode again... thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You could try:

```
List<int> ints = new List<int> {2, 5, 11, 15};
if (ints.Contains(id))
{
}
```

Though it might be slower than doing the switch.

However, it does have the advantage that (assuming that you initialise the list from data) you can use this to check on any list of integer values and aren't constrained to hard coded values.

Comment: Thanks, it would work. I like the Hashset a bit better because it performs better than `List<>`. Appreciate your answer though.

Comment: @Chad - no problem. My point about not having hard coded values is still relevant though....

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to be concise.

```
//
(new []{2, 5, 11, 15}).Contains(id)
//
```

If you want to be fast probably stick with the switch.

I think I like the HashSet though.

Comment: If they were sorted, you might as well make that: `Array.BinarySearch(new[] { ... }, id) != -1`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a solution using LINQ:

```
List<int> ints = new List<int> {2, 5, 11, 15};

void Search(int s) {
    int result = ints.Where(x => x == s).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
    bool exist = List.Init(6, 8, 2, 9, 12).Contains(8);

    foreach (int i in List.Init(6, 8, 2, 9, 12))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i.ToString());
    }



    public class List : IEnumerable<int>
    {
        private int[] _values;

        public List(params int[] values)
        {
            _values = values;
        }

        public static List Init(params int[] values)
        {
            return new List(values);
        }

        public IEnumerator<int> GetEnumerator()
        {
            foreach (int value in _values)
            {
                yield return value;
            }
        }

        public bool Contains(int value)
        {
            return Array.IndexOf(_values, value) > -1;
        }

        System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return GetEnumerator();
        }
    }
```